# deactivate USB driver on startup

Tags: ssh, drivers, usb

let me first start with a description of the problem. The problem is a device used for scientific research. I have intermediate experience with linux, but I am a scientist and not a sysadmin. We have a single-board computer (Kontron MOPSlcdLX PC/104), which is controlling a pulse generator. They are connected via USB.

During experimental procedure, this two devices are located out of reach. For that reason, we are communicating via SSH with the Kontron computer. Because of a possible loss of power connection, a restart of the Kontron computer sometimes occurs.

**The problem:** When the pulse generator is connected to the Kontron computer and we restart the whole system, the Kontron computer freezes. On ground, we solve this problem by first disconnecting the pulse generator, restarting the Kontron computer and then connecting the pulse generator again. However, this is not possible during normal experimental procedure.

We already deactivated the USB port in the BIOS before restart and the Kontron computer didn't freez. But this is not possible during normal experimental procedure, because we have only a SSH connection.

**The idea:** Deactivate USB for start up and activate it, when the computer is running via SSH.

**What we tried:**

Disable USB device:

```
echo '<bus>-1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

Copy the USB driver to another folder:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko
```

We also wanted to add the "nousb" option to grub, but we didn't know where to add it. But none of this helped. The computer froze during start up and without the pulse generator being connected the USB driver was actived.

The Kontron computer is running **Debian 7.2** and the **3.2.0-4-486 kernel**.

Thank you very much!